# How do I specify the PATH in NetBeans?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, path, netbeans6.8

When running Ruby code on NetBeans (like when running the tests) I'm having some failures because a program is not being found. That program is installed somewhere in /opt and while for the shell I get that added to my PATH, it seems NetBeans is not getting it.

How do I specify the PATH in NetBeans?

Answer (score 5):

In Unix, in your netbeans install directory (we'll call it $NETBEANS), there's an etc directory.

$NETBEANS/etc/netbeans.conf can be changed to add things to your PATH or set other environment variables for your Netbeans instances. I set some env variable for my Glassfish launches in there, for example.

Can't say for Windows.

Comment: That will get lost next time I upgrade or re-install it. Isn't it possible to define it in my user config?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I imagine there is another way of setting this configuration, but I do not know how to set environment variables for a user before the X Desktop starts, or before the Mac GUI starts. For windows, I believe the PATH is global so once set, it's set everywhere after you logout and log back in.

Comment: Nice. It works. It's much better then nothing or start NB all time from bash. Thanks.

Comment: Important things: you should use there `export` keyword before assigning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've had the same problem.
In .netbeans IDE Top Menu click "Run" and then "Set Project Configuration". Go through the options there and you'll find what you need.