# How to stop NetBeans from using Cygwin bin directory and make it use that of MSYS?

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin, mingw, msys

I have installed Cygwin at `C:\cygwin64` and MinGW at `C:\mingw\msys\1.0\opt\windows_64`.
Only MSYS and MinGW `bin` directories are in the PATH variable, Cygwin's is not. NetBeans is configured to use MinGW Tool Collection in `Tools > Options > C/C++ > Build Tools`.  The Make Command option is set to `C:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe`.

The problem comes when I run the tests (`Alt+F6`). I get the following error:

```
  2 [main] mkdir 888 c:\cygwin64\bin\mkdir.exe: *** fatal error - error while loading shared libraries: C: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
443 [main] mkdir 888 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to mkdir.exe.stackdump
```

Similar errors regarding `rm.exe` and `grep.exe`also appear. It seems that somehow NetBeans manages to find Cygwin binaries even though they are not in PATH. The binaries causing the errors are within MSYS `bin` directory (which is in PATH), but NetBeans does not see them.

Surprisingly the tests pass, but those errors make the compilation too slow.

I tried changing the name of Cygwin's installation directory to something else, and it works, but is not a good solution.

So how can I make NetBeans to forget `C:\cygwin64\bin` and use solely `C:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin`?

Comment: Maybe it's in the netbeans PATH. You might have to check it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551039/how-do-i-specify-the-path-in-netbeans).

Comment: @Thronghar As I am using Windows, I checked the C:\Program Files\NetBeans x.x.x\etc\netbeans.conf, but I did not find the PATH variable defined in there or any other configuration entry that might cause NetBeans to see Cygwin.

Comment: I'm now facing this issue and cannot even build my program in NetBeans. MSYS make runs cygwin mkdir and they are DLL incompatible.

Comment: Still an issue in 2020!!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the very same problem and I couldn't find proper solution. I can do a workaround and rename cygwin installation dir while I use NetBeans and then it works fine, but it is quite dirty. I just thought that at least workaround may help someone since this topic is opened for almost two years now :)

The reason why cygwin is used is unclear but if you go to "Tools"->"Open in Terminal" you immediately know two things:
- if it works, cygwin is referenced because terminal does not work with mingw
- $PATH variable starts with "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin", when checking /usr/bin, there are cygwin binaries

I assume that if cygwin folder gets renamed, the /usr/local/bin & /usr/bin fail to provide required binaries (like mv.exe, mkdir.exe...) and next folders in $PATH are used where Mingw kicks finally in.

As I said, I couldn't find proper configuration. I tried to modify %PATH% variable in windows but without any luck (cygwin is not even mentioned there).

Comment: This one is still an issue in 2020!!